# The Prophet's night Journey hadith

Tags: hadith-interpretation, surat-al-isra

Can someone explain what is meant by "green carpet spread all over the horizon" in this hadith? Is it possible that it's referring to the aurora lights? If someone could perhaps also share commentaries and references for this hadith:

> Regarding the Verse: "Indeed he (Muhammad) did see. Of the Signs of his Lord, The Greatest!" (53.18) **That the Prophet (ﷺ) had seen a green carpet spread all over the horizon of the sky.**
>
> [Sahih Bukhari 3233](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3233)

Answer (score 1):

“Whoever claimed that (the Prophet) Muhammad saw his Lord, is committing a great fault, for he only saw Gabriel in his genuine shape in which he was created covering the whole horizon.”

Sahih al-Bukhari 3234
In-book reference    : Book 59, Hadith 45
USC-MSA web (English) reference  : Vol. 4, Book 54, Hadith

I asked Aisha "What about His Statement:-- "Then he (Gabriel) approached And came closer, And was at a distance Of but two bow-lengths Or (even) nearer?" (53.8-9) She replied, "It was Gabriel who used to come to the Prophet (ﷺ) in the figure of a man, but on that occasion, he came in his actual and real figure and (he was so huge) that he covered the whole horizon."

Reference    : Sahih al-Bukhari 3235
In-book reference    : Book 59, Hadith 46
USC-MSA web (English) reference  : Vol. 4, Book

I looked further into the Hadith you were referencing and the 2 after that were these here. I’m assuming from reading the hadiths that it was Angel Jibra’eel. Please correct me if this wrong

EDIT-The above hadith has been mentioned by Imam Bukhari twice in his Sahih both places are mentioned in the Arabic texts.

"The Prophet S.A.W seen a green carpet spread all over the sky means that Gabriel A.S. spread of a single wing was like a green carpet. Gabriel A.S. has six hundred wings and if spreads a single wing it covers, the entire sky. This meaning is further substantiated by a Hadith mentioned by Imams Ahmad and Tirmidi.
عن عبد الرحمن بن يزيد عن ابن مسعود رضي الله عنه *"رأى جبريل في حلة من رفرف قد ملاء ما بين السماء والأرض"* وبهذه الرواية يعرف المراد بالرفرف وانه حلة
Gabriel A.S was wearing a cloak. رفرف means a pillow or flutter or flap of wings. The رفرف is made from silk brocade.
When Gabriel A.S spread his wing it seemed like a  silk spread.
والله أعلم وعلمه أتم

Comment: You should add this hadith as it clearly clarifies: https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:3283 "Rafraf" is the same word which was translated as a carpet in the question's hadith.

Comment: Yeah I should my bad

Comment: How can you prove that our Prophet (PBUH) did not saw Allah? I think this might be to some extent blasphemic or prove it otherwise.

Comment: Brother it’s sahih which means it’s authentic and there is literal translation which I have also quoted and I have put sources.

Comment: @Usman this was said by Aisha (RA) maybe she didn't know at the time?, indeed the Prophet (PBUH) saw Jibreel (AS) in his original form covering the horizon but there was also a point in the mairaj night journey where Jibreel (AS) and the Burraq were not able to go above / further and Jibreel (AS) said I may not go forth for If I do my wings will burn and then a force made the Prophet (PBUH) ascend and then he was at the arsh of Allah.

Comment: Because I also asked my uncle who is an imam for his views upon this Hadith and he also said the same thing. The edited part at the bottom was what he told me so. This specific part of the Hadith is also substantiated by 2 well knows scholars